# How do I use eslint to enforce JavaScript scoping of case statements within a switch?

Tags: javascript, jshint, lint, eslint

I'd like to create an eslint rule that enforces all case statements be scoped.

I realize not everyone prefers scoping case statements, but this is a personal preference to keep the codebase as consistent as possible.

**Non scoped example *(should produce an eslint error)***

```
export default function userReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.PROFILE_SAVE:
            return state;
    }

    return state;
}
```

**Scoped case statement *(should PASS eslinter)***

```
export default function userReducer(state = {}, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ActionType.PROFILE_SAVE: {
            return state;
        }
    }

    return state;
}
```

Is this possible? If so, how do I define that eslint rule?

Comment: Your question is *"Is this possible?"*. So you're looking for a "Yes" or "No" answer? Or are you trying to implement it, and are stuck?

Comment: Stuck. I just updated the question to reflect that so it's not ambiguous anymore.

Comment: I don't see that rule included in their built-in plugins. Maybe review the code in some of the others, and implement one. Seems like a useful idea. They do have an option to prevent lexical declaration in switch cases. If you implement this, you'll probably need to disallow `var` declarations in these blocks, since they'll escape that scope.

Comment: this is the rule that @squint mentioned. should probably cover the important case you're defending against http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-case-declarations

Comment: Wait... I think `case` statements are already scoped if you don't use `var`. https://jsfiddle.net/336gr4w9/

Comment: Ah, no-case-declarations was exactly it! Case statements aren't  scoped as I learned today actually. I had a const variableName declared in two different cases within a switch and got a linter error of
"'variableName' is already declared in the upper scope". Thanks for such a fast response!

Comment: Oh, I see. The switch itself creates a scope, but not per-case.